# php foreach returns last variable selected

Tags: php

the foreach doesn't seem to work correctly in which the last value selected is working but not all.

The array is selected from here:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>status:</legend>
    <?php foreach ($statuss as $status): ?>
      <div><label for="status<?php hscout($status['id']);
          ?>"><input type="checkbox" name="statuss1[]"
          id="status<?php hscout($status['id']); ?>"
          value="<?php hscout($status['id']); ?>"<?php
          if ($status['selected'])
          {
            echo ' checked="checked"';
          }
          ?>/><?php hscout($status['description']); ?></label></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </fieldset>
```

The index is as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['statuss1']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['statuss1'] as $status1)
{

$a = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $status1);

  $sql = "SELECT b FROM C WHERE d ='$a'";
  $result = mysqli_query($z, $sql);
  if (!$result)
  {
    $error = 'Still not working you.....';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
  }
  $selected1s = array();

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $selected1s[] = $row['b'];
  }
}
}
```

the `$selected1s[]` works only if one variable is selected. If multiple variables are selected, the last variable is parsed through.

Answer (score 1):

Every time through the `foreach` loop that fetches the selected items, you say `$selected1s = array()`, which clears out the array you're using to accumulate them.

Take the line that says `$selected1s = array();` and move it to before the `foreach` loop, if you just want to get this code working.

There's a way to build one query that gets all the rows at once, though.  That typically beats the pants off doing a whole bunch of queries for one item each.

```
$selected1s = array();

if (!empty($_POST['statuss1'])) {
    // Create a function that SQL-escapes and quotes an ID...
    // (Note: requires PHP 5.3+)
    $sqlify = function($id) use ($link) {
        return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $id) . "'";
    };
    // and apply it to the array to get back a list of SQL-ready values
    $ids = array_map($sqlify, $_POST['statuss1']);

    // string them together as a comma-separated list
    $ids_sql = implode(',', $ids);

    // and say `d IN (the list)`
    $sql = "SELECT b FROM c WHERE d IN ($ids_sql)";

    ... do the query, fetch results into $selected1s
}
```

(This is the part where i'd normally advocate prepared statements and tell you to use them.  Which you should, in most cases.  For `IN` queries or the equivalent `OR` queries, though, they tend to suck.)